# React async functions returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have a React Hook that calls the Refreshtoken on each page.

the Hook is this :

```js
const refresh = async (refToken) => {
  try {
    if (refToken && !functionalities.isTokenExpired(refToken)) {
      const ntoken = await refreshToken().then((obj) => {
        return obj.token;
      });          
      window.localStorage.setItem("token", ntoken);
    } else {
      window.localStorage.clear();
      toast.error("O seu acesso expirou! Faça novamente o login no sistema.");

      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error("Não foi possível atualizar o token do usuário");
  }
};

async function useRefreshToken() {
  const refToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken") || "";
  if (refToken && !functionalities.isTokenExpired(refToken)) {
    refresh(refToken).then(() => {});
    // setInterval(() => {
    //   refresh(refToken).then();
    // }, 3564000);
  }
}
// 0,99hrs 3564000 - 10min 600000 --
export default useRefreshToken;
```

but every time it runs it sets my token in the localstorage to undefined even with the server responding with the actual updated token:

```json
{"msg":"AUTHORIZATION SUCCESSFUL","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyVUlEIjoiZmZaTUZTTDF4UGNXdFQ5MDJkd2Z6RFB1WElEMyIsInBvc2l0aW9uIjoibWFuYWdlciIsImNvbXBhbnlJRCI6Ik14Z1ZleEhlSGZzN29ndTJaMm10IiwiaWF0IjoxNjU3MTQyMDU5LCJleHAiOjE2NTcxNDkyNTl9.l9OHl-84S5LrwF1r0fqQl2zuHhS-hrWaFj8QjrxDgQA"}
```

I'm not sure why is my code not waiting for the API response to update the token.

Additional info: the page I'm on calls the refreshToken at least 3 times every time I load them.

If someone could shed some light on me I would be grateful.

Edit:

refreshToken() is this call to the API:

```js
export const refreshToken = async () => {
  const headers = getDefaultHeaders(true);
  const refToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
  const body = {
    refreshToken: refToken,
  };
  return await axios.post(`${url}/auth/refreshToken`, body, headers);
};
```

Comment: what does `refreshToken()` return? It seems that promise isn't resolving to the object you expect it to - but you don't share that function so we can't possibly diagnose that further.

Comment: @RobinZigmond - edited the question with the axios request 'refreshToken()' , it responds with a AxiosResponse primise.

Comment: Make sure the API response with header `Content-type: application/json`.

Comment: @Hereblur the API is responding with `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: can you console.log(obj.token) here: `const ntoken = await refreshToken().then((obj) => {
        return obj.token;
      });

Comment: it returns `undefined`, but when I look in the network log, I see that Refreshtoken responded like this `{res: SUCSESS MESSAGE, token: TOKEN KEY}`, what i'm not getting is why this asyncronous function is not working as it should.

Comment: there isn't enough information here to enable us to say for sure what the problem is. But we need to know what `obj` (the response from your API to the POST request) is, in full. My suspicion is that the object you've shown us, which includes the `token` value, may actually not be the whole response object but just the value held in one property.

Comment: Axios return whole response object not just the body, try to access your token by `obj.data.token` 
https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

Answer (score 0):

I think because localStorage set your token before your refresh token return. You can try put `window.localStorage.setItem("token", ntoken);` into response of refreshtoken(). If it does not work console.log your `obj` return may be there miss spell of `token`

```js
    const ntoken = await refreshToken().then((obj) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem("token", ntoken);
        return obj.token;
      });
```